# Character select in arena

Tags: hearthstone

When you enter the arena you are given 3 random champions to select from. I was wondering:

- Are these heroes truly selected at random?
- Does the game give everyone the same 3 heroes on the same day?
- Is there a rotation in order if this is the case?
- If I enter the arena and I hate the Heroes I am given, will they ever reset if I don't select one?

Comment: Your hero choices won't reset until you start a new arena.

Comment: I only know two of these: 
~Not everyone gets the same 3 Heros each day.
~Closing out of the arena and coming back will always be the same Heros   for that particular arena run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The classes available in the arena, as well as the cards available when constructing your deck, are both entirely random.

Once you "Buy-In" to the Arena, you are locked to those options until you win 12 times, lose 3 times, or retire. Your status in the Arena is otherwise saved in perpetuum.

Comment: Seeing as how one pays/"pays" to enter the arena... I think this is kind of beat up.

Comment: @Grohlier It's the psychology of freemium; at the lower level, make your game appear to be about skill, while at the higher level, make the game much more based about luck (which cards you draw, etc). The end result - more folks spend real money.

Comment: @ RavenDreamer I think, then, that my quest gold would be much better spent on card packs rather than the chance at cards from arenas. If I wanted to stay free-to-play of course.

Comment: I would say the Arena is the place where you have the best chance to show your skill in the game. The cards are random so it is your ability to choose what works that come in to play and since it does not use your own cards, it does not matter how much real life money you have spend on the game once you enter the arena.

Comment: @Blem Yeah, but luck still plays a higher part in arena games, since you can (but won't always) draw Legendaries in deck construction. Hard to play against Ysera or Archmage Antonidas even *with* a Play deck.

But that's the point -- you get completely trashed in Arena by some guy who manages to play Deathwing, and you are drawn in to keep playing Arena (hopefully via real money!) for that chance to draw an elusive, insta-win card you can wreck with on your own.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I think Arena requires a lot more skill because you have to develop a strategy around the randomness. RNG plays a huge factor, but good players (the top tier) will still be regularly performing in the top. Personally, I have averaged 6 wins per arena in 19 runs so far (exactly 6, tracking results in excel) using each class. I have more 9s & 8s than 2s & 3s, and no 0s or 1s. Results like that, 19 times, to me proves that luck is a small factor compared to skill. I would have to agree with Blem, Arena is the best test of skill.